# How do I hide a form on submission and show the result at the same time?

Tags: php, html, forms, show-hide

I am making a a form but I doesn't work like I want it to. This is the code:

```
<?php
  $output = '';
  $display_form = True;
  //echo $display_form;
  //Once the form is submitted it should be hidden so first I set $display_form to false at line 19.
  //Then I do all the logic to get the propper result at line 21-39. And echo the result at line 40-43.
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $display_form = False;

    if (!is_numeric($_POST['mark1'])) {
      $mark1 = $_POST['mark1'];

      $output = 'De invoer van Getal 1 was foutief: '.$mark1;
    }if(!is_numeric($_POST['mark2'])) {
      $mark2 = $_POST['mark2'];

      $output.= '<br>De invoer van Getal 2 was foutief '.$mark2;
    }elseif(is_numeric($_POST['mark1']) && is_numeric($_POST['mark2'])){
        $mark1 = str_replace(',', '.', $_POST['mark1']);
        $mark2 = str_replace(',', '.', $_POST['mark2']);
        $result = $mark1+$mark2;

        $mark1_2 = str_replace('.', ',', $mark1);
        $mark2_2 = str_replace('.', ',', $mark2);
        $result_2 = str_replace('.', ',', $result);

        $output = $mark1_2.' + '.$mark2_2. ' = '.$result_2.'<br>';
    }?>
    <h1>
      <?php echo $output ?>
    </h1>
    <button type="reset" value="Opnieuw">Opnieuw</button>
    <?php
  }

  //If the form isn't submitted $display_form is True so it should show this HTML
  if($display_form){ ?>
    <h1>Optel rekenmachine</h1>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      Getal 1: <input type="text" name="mark1"><br>
      Getal 2: <input type="text" name="mark2"><br>
      <button type="submit" value="Optellen!"class="form">Optellen!</button><button type="reset" value="Leegmaken">Leegmaken</button>
    </form>
<?php }
?>
```

I want it to show the form, but once it is submitted I want the form to hide en de results to show. When the results are shown there is a 'Opnieuw' button. Once that's clicked the form should show itself again and the results with the opnieuw button should hide. But right now the form doesn't give the results nor hide but just resets once it is submitted.

Comment: a `name="submit"` in the button is missing, so `$_POST['submit']` will not be set -> make it `<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Optellen!" class="form">`

Comment: @Jeff Thx now it hides! But the 'Opnieuw' button still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button doesn't have a name attribute set, so wont send anything that you can check for in $_POST. So add `name="submit"` to that button:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Optellen!" class="form">
```

To make the "Opnieuw" button do something wrap it in a form to the same script (without any values)

Comment: Thx it works now! I needed to add `<a href="PO12%20(v.2).php?display_form=true">Opnieuw</a>` for the 'Opnieuw' button to work.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: The `..?display_form=true` won't do anything though (the way the rest of your code is now), because you don't check for `$_GET['display_form']`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this using the $_POST array, which exists only if there was data sent.

```
if (isset($_POST)) {

    //do your stuff with the data from the form so here basically echo $output

else {

    //echo your form

}
```

No need to use a "$display_form" variable.

You also **don't need** to set a name for the submit input, but since it is a good practice to set a name for every input then i suggest you have to do it anyway.